# Jackson deserialize with variable interpolation

Tags: java, json, jackson, token, interpolation

How to custom Jackson to deserialize a value that contains a `${token}` ?

Here is an example of the functionnality that i want to add from the [Apache Commons Configuration variable interpolation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation) :

```
{
    "file" = "${sys:user.home}/path/to/my_file"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a [custom string deserialiser](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) based on the default which would interpolate the variables after the deserialisation.

But, as was pointed out in the comments, that would not work for the non-String types such as File and URLs. The better idea is to override the `getText()` and `getValueAsString()` methods of the `JsonParser` by passing a custom `JsonFactory`.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonInterpolateString {
    static final String JSON = "{ \"file\":\"${sys:user.home}/path/to/my_file\" }";

    public static class Bean {
        public File file;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return file.toString();
        }
    }

    private static class MyJsonParser extends JsonParserDelegate {

        public MyJsonParser(final JsonParser d) {
            super(d);
        }

        @Override
        public String getText() throws IOException {
            final String value = super.getText();
            if (value != null) {
                return interpolateString(value);
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String getValueAsString() throws IOException {
            return getValueAsString(null);
        }

        @Override
        public String getValueAsString(final String defaultValue) throws IOException {
            final String value = super.getValueAsString(defaultValue);
            if (value != null) {
                return interpolateString(value);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class MyMappingJsonFactory extends MappingJsonFactory {
        @Override
        protected JsonParser _createParser(
                final char[] data,
                final int offset,
                final int len,
                final IOContext ctxt,
                final boolean recyclable)
                throws IOException {
            return new MyJsonParser(super._createParser(data, offset, len, ctxt, recyclable));
        }

        @Override
        protected JsonParser _createParser(final Reader r, final IOContext ctxt)
                throws IOException {
            return new MyJsonParser(super._createParser(r, ctxt));
        }

    }

    private static String interpolateString(final String value) {
        return value.replace("${sys:user.home}", "/home/user");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final JsonFactory factory = new MyMappingJsonFactory();
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Map.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Bean.class));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{file=/home/user/path/to/my_file}
/home/user/path/to/my_file
```

Comment: his solution only works if i want to deserialize `String`, but how to apply the transformation on each deserializer type (i.e Path)? I think i have to create a `JsonParser` to override the `getText` or `getValusAsString`?

Comment: @gulecroc good point! I have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: sounds good! I was stuck by overriding the `JsonParser`, didn't know about `JsonParserDelegate`! And sorry not enough reputation to vote up ... so +1

Comment: @GuillaumeLecroc I'm glad that it works! This is actually a good question and (I hope) a good answer which could potentially help others. I believe that you should be able to accept the answer even though you have little reputation. Here is a link on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: How might one use this in conjunction with YAML?  I've tried various methods of chaining the factories/setting codecs, but I'm not very well versed in Jackson.