# How to apply low-level character filter to Jackson JSON parsing?

Tags: json, jackson, resteasy

I have a (JSON) REST-based application based on Spring and RESTEasy. We have a requirement to limit the set of characters that are accepted as input to the services. I *could* apply the restriction to the POJOs themselves during or after deserialization, but it seems more efficient to insert some kind of filter into the Jackson parsing as it's reading the JSON stream, since it's obviously inspecting each character at some point anyway.

Question is, does Jackson provide a plug-in point to do that? Something that would enable me to decorate or override the low-level parsing at such a time that I could verify each character of each property value is valid (i.e., in a particular set according to the app requirements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean allowed characters within JSON String values, no, there is no filter or transformer functionality currently. You could consider implementing `JsonParserDelegate`, which could intercept calls to `getText()`, but that may not be very clean mechanism. Alternatively you could first read content as tree (`JsonNode`), traverse it and cleanse String values; and only after that do data-binding using `ObjectMapper.convertValue(fromNode, MyType.class)`.

In the context of RESTEasy, you can inject the custom `JsonParserDelegate` by extending `MappingJsonFactory` and overriding the `_createJsonParser(...)` methods to return the custom delegate. Then implement an extension to `JacksonJsonProvider` (Jackson's JAX-RS provider) that creates an `ObjectMapper` with your custom factory in its constructor. Examples of this can be found in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26607804/639520).

Comment: `JsonParserDelegate` looks promising for my purpose. Any idea how a delegate can be configured for the parser that RESTEasy uses? Or, more likely, how does one normally configure a custom delegate and maybe I can find out if/how RESTEasy exposes that.

Comment: @E-Riz unfortunately I do not know how this could be done in context of declarative handling (data-binding of POJOs). You might have to sub-class `JsonFactory` and override `createParser()` methods, register `ObjectMapper` that uses this factory.

Comment: I edited the answer with some details on how to integrate with RESTEasy